# How can i make a chatbot with Google Bard?

Tags: visual-studio, discord.js, bots

I would like to make a chatbot using Google Bard. I tried using Chatgpt but I ran into some errors and gave up.

Right now I just need the base code. It's simply that I send a message, and the bot responds.

Now because there are close to 0 tutorials I used Google Bard itself so I'm well aware
some things are wrong. I just don't know what.

Heres my current code:

```
const {Dialogflow} = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow');

const dialogflow = new Dialogflow({
  projectId: 'my project id',
  credentials: {
    key: 'my api key',
  },
});

// Create a variable to store the conversation state.
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent ] });

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log('Bot is ready!')
})
const ignore = '!' && '?'
const botchanelid = '1155186010485960909'

client.on('messageCreate', async (msg) => {
if (msg.content.startsWith(ignore) || msg.channelId  != botchanelid || msg.author.bot) return;
dialogflow.query(`${msg}`, conversationState, (err, response) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  // Get the response from Dialogflow.
  const responseText = response.result.text;

  // Update the conversation state.
  conversationState = response.result.conversationState;

  // Display the response to the user.
msg.reply(responseText)
})
})
```

Right now my error is `TypeError: Dialogflow is not a constructor`. I would like an answer
that tells me what I'm doing wrong, and fully adjust it so I understand.

My version is 6.1.0.

Please lmk in the comments if you need any extra info!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an enhanced code:

````js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const dialogflow = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
});

// Initialize Dialogflow client
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
  projectId: 'your-project-id',
  credentials: {
    client_email: 'your-client-email',
    private_key: 'your-private-key',
  },
});

const botChannelId = 'your-bot-channel-id';

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot is ready!');
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (msg) => {
  if (msg.content.startsWith('!') || msg.content.startsWith('?') || msg.channelId !== botChannelId || msg.author.bot) {
    return;
  }

  // Create a new session
  const sessionPath = sessionClient.projectAgentSessionPath('your-project-id', 'unique-session-id');

  // The text query request to Dialogflow
  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        text: msg.content,
        languageCode: 'en-US', // Replace with the appropriate language code
      },
    },
  };

  try {
    const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);

    const responseText = responses[0].queryResult.fulfillmentText;
    msg.reply(responseText);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error communicating with Dialogflow:', error);
  }
});

// Log in to Discord with your bot's token
client.login('your-bot-token');```


Well, the fix is:
In your code, you have the following import statement:
```lang-js const {Dialogflow} = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow');```
Change to
```lang-js const dialogflow = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow');```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).